# How to script out the grant view on login permission?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions, scripting, logins

I create the following login **without any permissions**.

```
USE [master]
GO

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'Radhe')
    CREATE LOGIN [Radhe] WITH PASSWORD=N'HareKrishna108, 
    DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
    GO
```

when I execute the following query as that specific login I get the following results:

```
execute as login='Radhe'

select * from sys.syslogins
```

[image]

Now I grant some permissions to `[Radhe]` so that she can have a look at some of my existing logins on that same server:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::[site_helpdesk] TO [Radhe]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::[camper] TO [Radhe]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::[productuser] TO [Radhe]
```

Now when I run the following code:

```
execute as login='Radhe'

select * from sys.syslogins
```

I get to see the logins I have granted `[Radhe]` the relevant permissions:

[image]

I need to create this very same login and grant these very same permissions on several servers.

**How can I script these permissions that I have granted above?**

I have found [the following script on this nice site](http://udayarumilli.com/script-login-user-permissions-sql-server/), but it does not seem to be working for the above listed permissions in particular:

```
--https://www.datavail.com/blog/scripting-out-the-logins-server-role-assignments-and-server-permissions/
/********************************************************************************************************************/
-- Scripting Out the Logins, Server Role Assignments, and Server Permissions
/********************************************************************************************************************/
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Scripting Out the Logins To Be Created
SELECT 'IF (SUSER_ID('+QUOTENAME(SP.name,'''')+') IS NULL) BEGIN CREATE LOGIN ' +QUOTENAME(SP.name)+
               CASE 
                    WHEN SP.type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN' THEN ' WITH PASSWORD = ' +CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),SL.password_hash,1)+ ' HASHED, CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' 
                        + CASE WHEN SL.is_expiration_checked = 1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END +', CHECK_POLICY = ' +CASE WHEN SL.is_policy_checked = 1 THEN 'ON,' ELSE 'OFF,' END
                    ELSE ' FROM WINDOWS WITH'
                END 
       +' DEFAULT_DATABASE=[' +SP.default_database_name+ '], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[' +SP.default_language_name+ '] END;' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [-- Logins To Be Created --]
FROM sys.server_principals AS SP LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins AS SL
        ON SP.principal_id = SL.principal_id
WHERE SP.type IN ('S','G','U')
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND SP.name <> ('sa');

-- Scripting Out the Role Membership to Be Added
SELECT 
'EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N''' + SL.name + ''', @rolename = N''' + SR.name + '''
' AS [-- Server Roles the Logins Need to be Added --]
FROM master.sys.server_role_members SRM
    JOIN master.sys.server_principals SR ON SR.principal_id = SRM.role_principal_id
    JOIN master.sys.server_principals SL ON SL.principal_id = SRM.member_principal_id
WHERE SL.type IN ('S','G','U')
        AND SL.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND SL.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND SL.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND SL.name <> ('sa');


-- Scripting out the Permissions to Be Granted
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
        THEN SrvPerm.state_desc 
        ELSE 'GRANT' 
    END
    + ' ' + SrvPerm.permission_name + ' TO [' + SP.name + ']' + 
    CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
        THEN '' 
        ELSE ' WITH GRANT OPTION' 
    END collate database_default AS [-- Server Level Permissions to Be Granted --] 
FROM sys.server_permissions AS SrvPerm 
    JOIN sys.server_principals AS SP ON SrvPerm.grantee_principal_id = SP.principal_id 
WHERE   SP.type IN ( 'S', 'U', 'G' ) 
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND SP.name <> ('sa');

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server permission for granting rights against logins has a class_desc of `SERVER_PRINCIPAL`. So in that case you can include the `ON LOGIN::` bits and join (again) against `sys.server_principals`. Also tell radhe and others to please use that view instead of `sys.syslogins`, which was deprecated 13 years ago now...

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
        THEN SrvPerm.state_desc 
        ELSE 'GRANT' 
    END
    + ' ' + SrvPerm.permission_name 
    + CASE SrvPerm.class_desc WHEN 'SERVER_PRINCIPAL' THEN 
      ' ON LOGIN::' + QUOTENAME(t.name) ELSE '' END
    + ' TO [' + SP.name + ']' + 
    CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
        THEN '' 
        ELSE ' WITH GRANT OPTION' 
    END collate database_default AS [-- Server Level Permissions to Be Granted --] 
FROM sys.server_permissions AS SrvPerm 
    INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS SP 
    ON SrvPerm.grantee_principal_id = SP.principal_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals AS t
    ON SrvPerm.major_id = t.principal_id
WHERE   SP.type IN ( 'S', 'U', 'G' ) 
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND SP.name <> ('sa');
```

Results:

```
GRANT CONNECT SQL TO [Radhe]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::[site_helpdesk] TO [Radhe]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::[camper] TO [Radhe]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::[productuser] TO [Radhe]
```