# how to script server side permissions - specifically EXECUTE ON SYS.XP_PROP_OLEDB_PROVIDER?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, security, scripting, automation

I could not script the following server side permissions:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::[site_helpdesk] TO [Radhe]
```

but thanks to the question below I found a solution to that:

[How to script out the grant view on login permission?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218273/22336)

Now I have a similar problem:

I have a process that grant the following server side permission to a login:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.XP_PROP_OLEDB_PROVIDER TO [my_company\my_login]
```

that is working fine, however, I need to script all the permissions of the `my_company\my_login` but I cannot find a way to script this permission.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `sys.server_principals` and `sys.database_permissions` holds information about server level access/permissions, information similar to that `sys.database_principals' and`sys.database_permission` holds information about database level access/permissions.

Joining these two objects with `UNION` of `sys.objects` and `sys.sysobjects` will give you desired information about user defined and system objects, which can be converted into script.

Note: To generate script for object level permission we need to execute the script in respective database. Like `sys.xp_prop_oledb_provide` is an object of master database, so we'll execute the `SELECT` statement in master database.

Example:-

```
CREATE LOGIN Radhe WITH PASSWORD='HareKrishna001!', DEFAULT_DATABASE=master;
GO

CREATE USER Radhe FOR LOGIN Radhe;
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.XP_PROP_OLEDB_PROVIDER TO [Radhe];
GO

USE master;
GO
select
        case when DBPerm.state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' then 'GRANT' else DBPerm.state_desc end COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS+
        ' '+DBPerm.permission_name  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS+' ON '+o.objectschema+'.'+o.name+' TO ['+DBPrin.name+']'+
         case when DBPerm.state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' then 'WITH GRANT OPTION;' else ';' end COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [Script]
from
            sys.database_permissions DBPerm
inner join  (
            select name,object_id,schema_name(schema_id) objectschema from sys.objects
            union all
            select name,id,'sys' as objectschema from sys.sysobjects
            ) o
on          DBPerm.major_id=o.object_id
inner join  sys.database_principals DBPrin
on          DBPerm.grantee_principal_id=DBPrin.principal_id
where
            DBPrin.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND DBPrin.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND DBPrin.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND DBPrin.name not in ('sa','public');
```

Results to:

```
Script
-------------------------------------------------------------
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.xp_prop_oledb_provider TO [Radhe]
```

Hare Krishna!

Comment: Hare Krishna! That's great, from now on I will remember the permissions on `master` and `msdb` when referring to `server side permissions`