# Reinstalling server and SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, windows-server

Due to some Windows issue, can't clean-up the WinSxS folder and the Disk Space process (cleanmgr.exe) makes the CPU going to 100% meaning that I am at 97% of disk usage, I am planning to reinstall the server where my SQL engine is running.

I know I have to backup the databases, fine with that. How do I backup the login and their rights ? I have got also some jobs I would like to backup. Anything else I should think of ? Should I backup and restore the master db or any other system databases ?

Consider I have got 72 databases and 85 logins so I wouldn't want to do that one x one.

My server is a Windows Server 2016 running a SQL Server 2016. The reinstallation of the OS and SQL Server engine will be done for me by my provider.

Answer (score 2):

For the logins [Transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances)

For the jobs, just script them with SSMS.

Test all this on a VM before you lose you server. You don't want to miss scripting something like Linked Servers, 3rd-party drivers, replication configuration, local users, certificates, credentials.

Comment: For the logins I found this which appears doing what I need https://docs.dbatools.io/Export-DbaLogin

Comment: dbatools is well-regarded.

Answer (score 0):

for the jobs, if you backup the msdb database and later on restore it to your new server all your jobs will be there.

you can also script them and apply them to the new server.

make sure you script all the logins and permissions first. save the script to apply in the new server.
then you can restore the msdb database `with replace`.

do this before restoring any user database.

for the logins I use the following procedure:
It also scripts the server permissions and takes special care on system objects like permissions on logins and endpoints.

I will show you how to use it later on in this post:

```
use master
go

--==================================================================================
-- Create shell.
--==================================================================================

IF object_id('sp_getthelogins') IS NULL EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getthelogins AS PRINT ''Krishna Krishna''')
go

GO
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_getthelogins
     @radhe sysname=null,
     @login_name sysname = NULL,
     @WITH_PRINT bit = 1
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS
/*
=======================================================================
Script  :   sp_getthelogins
Author  :   Marcello Miorelli
Date    :   20-dec-2018
Desc    :   this procedure returns ithe logins and the script as how to create them
        
Usage   :  
               --===============================================================================================================
               -- this way below it works, by passing a temp table as a parameter
               --===============================================================================================================

                if OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Jagannatha') IS NOT NULL
                   DROP TABLE #Jagannatha

                CREATE TABLE #Jagannatha(
                    I                        INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
                    Servername               SYSNAME        COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NOT NULL,
                    NAME                     SYSNAME        COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NOT NULL,
                    the_type                 SYSNAME        COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NOT NULL,
                    script                   varchar(4000)  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SERVERNAME,NAME,I)
                ) 

                exec sp_getthelogins 
                     @Radhe ='#Jagannatha',
                     @WITH_PRINT=0

                select *
                from #Jagannatha
                --ORDER BY NAME
                --ORDER BY I



Links:

-- How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server
-- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server

-- Scripting Out the Logins, Server Role Assignments, and Server Permissions
-- https://www.datavail.com/blog/scripting-out-the-logins-server-role-assignments-and-server-permissions/

-- [How to script out the grant view on login permission?][1]
-- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218273/22336


=======================================================================
History
Date          Action        User                Desc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
20-dec-2018  created       Marcello Miorelli
23-dec-2018  ammended      M.M.                 only inserts into table @Radhe if it exists, passed as parameter
28-dec-2018  new features  M.M.                 added the server roles and the server permissions for each login
17-Jan-2019  fixes         M.M.                 fixes in the script
09-Feb-2022  ammended      M.M.                 parameter @WITH_PRINT - only prints if that is on
15-Mar-2022  ammended      M.M.                 added the grant on login and grant on endpoint permissions
=======================================================================
*/

--======================================
-- describe primary blocks of processing
--======================================

------------------------------------------------
-- describe action of logical groups of commANDs
------------------------------------------------

-- describe individual actions within a commAND set

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    DECLARE  @log NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Object_ID INT  
    DECLARE @DB_ID INT
    DECLARE @Object_ID_STR VARCHAR(15) 
    DECLARE @Object_TYPE VARCHAR(3)

    DECLARE  @DBName sysname
            ,@vCrlf CHAR(2);

    DECLARE @ERR_SEV   SMALLINT,
            @ERR_STA   SMALLINT


DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @name sysname
DECLARE @type varchar (1)
DECLARE @hasaccess int
DECLARE @denylogin int
DECLARE @is_disabled int
DECLARE @PWD_varbinary  varbinary (256)
DECLARE @PWD_string  varchar (514)
DECLARE @SID_varbinary varbinary (85)
DECLARE @SID_string varchar (514)
DECLARE @script  varchar (4000)
DECLARE @is_policy_checked varchar (3)
DECLARE @is_expiration_checked varchar (3)

DECLARE @defaultdb sysname
DECLARE @TT SYSNAME -- THE_TYPE



--=========================================================================================================
--=========================================================================================================

BEGIN TRY

        SELECT @TT = '1 - Login creation'
        IF (@login_name IS NULL)
          DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

                 SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin 
                   FROM sys.server_principals p 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.syslogins l
                     ON ( l.name = p.name ) WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) 
                    AND p.name <> 'sa'
                    AND P.sid <> 0x01  -- 0x01 is either SA or a login with that position for example dude

        ELSE
          DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR


                 SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin 
                   FROM sys.server_principals p 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.syslogins l
                     ON ( l.name = p.name ) 
                  WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) 
                    AND p.name = @login_name

        OPEN login_curs

        FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
        IF (@@fetch_status = -1)
        BEGIN

          IF @WITH_PRINT = 1 
             PRINT 'No login(s) found.'

          CLOSE login_curs
          DEALLOCATE login_curs
          RETURN -1
        END

        SET @script = '/* sp_getthelogins script '
          IF @WITH_PRINT = 1 
             PRINT @script

        SET @script = '** Generated ' + CONVERT (varchar, GETDATE()) + ' on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' */'

          IF @WITH_PRINT = 1 
             PRINT @script

          IF @WITH_PRINT = 1 
             PRINT ''

        WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
        BEGIN

          IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
          BEGIN

          IF @WITH_PRINT = 1 
             PRINT ''

            SET @script = '-- Login: ' + @name

          IF @WITH_PRINT = 1 
             PRINT @script

            IF (@type IN ( 'G', 'U'))
            BEGIN -- NT authenticated account/group

              SET @script = CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + 
                            'IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sys.server_principals SP' + CHAR(10) +
                            '                        where SP.name = ' + '''' + @name + ''''  + ')' + CHAR(10) + 
                            'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']' + ';' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10)
            END
            ELSE BEGIN -- SQL Server authentication

                -- obtain password and sid
                    SET @PWD_varbinary = CAST( LOGINPROPERTY( @name, 'PasswordHash' ) AS varbinary (256) )
                EXEC sp_hexadecimal @PWD_varbinary, @PWD_string OUT
                EXEC sp_hexadecimal @SID_varbinary,@SID_string OUT
 
                -- obtain password policy state
                SELECT @is_policy_checked = CASE is_policy_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name
                SELECT @is_expiration_checked = CASE is_expiration_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name
 

                SET @script = CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) +
                            'IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sys.server_principals SP ' + CHAR(10) +
                            '               where SP.name = ' + '''' + @name + ''''  + ')' + CHAR(10) + 
                            'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + CHAR(10) +  
                            ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED,' + CHAR(10) +  
                            ' SID = ' + @SID_string + ',' + CHAR(10) + 
                            ' DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']' 

                IF ( @is_policy_checked IS NOT NULL )
                BEGIN
                  SET @script = @script + ',CHECK_POLICY = ' + @is_policy_checked
                END
                IF ( @is_expiration_checked IS NOT NULL )
                BEGIN
                  SET @script = @script + ',CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' + @is_expiration_checked
                END

                SET @script = @script + ';' + CHAR(10) 

            END

            IF (@denylogin = 1)
            BEGIN -- login is denied access
              SET @script = @script + CHAR(10) + 
              ' DENY CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ';'
            END
            ELSE IF (@hasaccess = 0)
            BEGIN -- login exists but does not have access
              SET @script = @script  + CHAR(10) + 
              ' REVOKE CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ';'
            END
            IF (@is_disabled = 1)
            BEGIN -- login is disabled
              SET @script = @script  + CHAR(10) + 
              ' ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' DISABLE' + ';' + CHAR(10)
            END

            if @WITH_PRINT=1
               PRINT @script

            IF @radhe IS NOT NULL
               BEGIN
                        --=============================================================
                        -- INSERTS INTO THE @Radhe table - if one was provided
                        --=============================================================
                        -- generate the script to load into the table
                        select @sql = case when @radhe IS not null then 
                                                N'
                                                insert into ' + @radhe + N'(Servername,name,the_type,script) values(@@servername,@name,@the_type,@script)'
                                            else N'' 
                                        end 

                        --set the parameters                      
                        SET @ParamDefinition = N'@name sysname,
                                                 @the_type sysname,
                                                 @script VARCHAR(4000)';

                        --insert the values into the table 
                        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, @name=@name, @script=@script, @the_type=@tt
               END 

          END
          FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
        END

        begin try
           CLOSE login_curs
        end try
        begin catch 
        end catch

        begin try
          DEALLOCATE login_curs
        end try
        begin catch 
        end catch

        SELECT @TT = '2 - Server Role Membership'
        --============================================================================================
        -- Scripting Out the Role Membership to Be Added
        --============================================================================================

            IF @radhe IS NOT NULL
               BEGIN
                        --=============================================================
                        -- INSERTS INTO THE @Radhe table - if one was provided
                        --=============================================================
                        -- generate the script to load into the table
                        select @sql = case when @radhe IS not null then 
                                                N'
                                                insert into ' + @radhe + N'(Servername,name,the_type,script) 
                                                SELECT  @@servername,
                                                        SL.name,
                                                        @the_type,' +                                               
        '''EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'''''' + SL.name + '''''', @rolename = N'''''' + SR.name + ''''''
        ''' + ' AS [-- Server Roles the Logins Need to be Added --] ' +
                                                'FROM master.sys.server_role_members SRM
                                                            JOIN master.sys.server_principals SR ON SR.principal_id = SRM.role_principal_id
                                                            JOIN master.sys.server_principals SL ON SL.principal_id = SRM.member_principal_id
                                                        WHERE SL.type IN (''S'',''G'',''U'')
                                                                --AND SL.name NOT LIKE ''##%##''
                                                                --AND SL.name NOT LIKE ''NT AUTHORITY%''
                                                                --AND SL.name NOT LIKE ''NT SERVICE%''
                                                                AND SL.name <> (''sa'')
                                                                AND SL.sid <> 0x01  -- 0x01 is either SA or a login with that position for example dude     
                                                '
                                            else N'' 
                                        end 

                        --set the parameters                      
                        SET @ParamDefinition = N'@the_type sysname';

                        --insert the values into the table 
                        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, @the_type=@tt
               END 

        SELECT @TT = '3 - Server Permissions to Be Granted'
        --============================================================================================
        -- -- Scripting out the Permissions to Be Granted
        --============================================================================================

            IF @radhe IS NOT NULL
               BEGIN
                        --=============================================================
                        -- INSERTS INTO THE @Radhe table - if one was provided
                        --=============================================================
                        -- generate the script to load into the table
                        select @sql = case when @radhe IS not null then 
                                                N'
                                                insert into ' + @radhe + N'(Servername,name,the_type,script) 
                                                SELECT 
                                                    @@servername,
                                                    SP.name,
                                                    @THE_TYPE,
                                                    CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> ''GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'' 
                                                        THEN SrvPerm.state_desc 
                                                        ELSE ''GRANT'' 
                                                    END
                                                    + '' '' + SrvPerm.permission_name 
                                                    + CASE SrvPerm.class_desc WHEN ''SERVER_PRINCIPAL'' THEN 
                                                      '' ON LOGIN::'' + QUOTENAME(t.name) ELSE '''' END
                                                    + CASE SrvPerm.class_desc WHEN ''ENDPOINT'' THEN 
                                                      '' ON ENDPOINT::'' + QUOTENAME(e.name) ELSE '''' END
                                                    + '' TO ['' + SP.name + '']'' + 
                                                    CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> ''GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'' 
                                                        THEN '''' 
                                                        ELSE '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
                                                    END collate database_default AS [-- Server Level Permissions to Be Granted --] 
                                                FROM sys.server_permissions AS SrvPerm 
                                                    INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS SP 
                                                    ON SrvPerm.grantee_principal_id = SP.principal_id 
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals AS t
                                                    ON SrvPerm.major_id = t.principal_id
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.endpoints AS e
                                                    ON SrvPerm.major_id = e.endpoint_id
                                                WHERE   SP.type IN ( ''S'', ''U'', ''G'' ) 
                                                        AND SP.name NOT LIKE ''##%##''
                                                        AND SP.name NOT LIKE ''NT AUTHORITY%''
                                                        AND SP.name NOT LIKE ''NT SERVICE%''
                                                        AND SP.sid <> 0x01  -- 0x01 is either SA or a login with that position for example dude     
                                                '
                                            else N'' 
                                        end 

                        --set the parameters                      
                        SET @ParamDefinition = N'@the_type sysname';

                        --insert the values into the table 
                        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, @the_type=@tt
               END 
        RETURN 0


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH


        begin try
           CLOSE login_curs
        end try
        begin catch 
        end catch

        begin try
          DEALLOCATE login_curs
        end try
        begin catch 
        end catch

    DECLARE @ERRORMESSAGE    NVARCHAR(512),
            @ERRORSEVERITY   INT,
            @ERRORNUMBER     INT,
            @ERRORSTATE      INT,
            @ERRORPROCEDURE  SYSNAME,
            @ERRORLINE       INT,
            @XASTATE         INT

    SELECT
            @ERRORMESSAGE     = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ERRORSEVERITY    = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ERRORNUMBER      = ERROR_NUMBER(),
            @ERRORSTATE       = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ERRORPROCEDURE   = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
            @ERRORLINE        = ERROR_LINE()

    SET @ERRORMESSAGE = 
    (
    SELECT                    CHAR(13) +
      'Message:'         +    SPACE(1) + @ErrorMessage                           + SPACE(2) + CHAR(13) +
      'Error:'           +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorNumber)      + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Severity:'        +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorSeverity)    + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'State:'           +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorState)       + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Routine_Name:'    +    SPACE(1) + COALESCE(@ErrorProcedure,'')            + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Line:'            +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorLine)        + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Executed As:'     +    SPACE(1) + SYSTEM_USER + SPACE(1)                             + CHAR(13) +
      'Database:'        +    SPACE(1) + DB_NAME() + SPACE(1)                               + CHAR(13) +
      'OSTime:'          +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,121)        + CHAR(13) 
    )

    --We can also save the error details to a table for later reference here.
    RAISERROR (@ERRORMESSAGE,16,1)

        RETURN (-1)
  
END CATCH;

GO

exec sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject 'sp_getthelogins'
```

and one way to use it is:

```
                if OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Jagannatha') IS NOT NULL
               DROP TABLE #Jagannatha

            CREATE TABLE #Jagannatha(
                I                        INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
                Servername               SYSNAME        COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NOT NULL,
                NAME                     SYSNAME        COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NOT NULL,
                the_type                 SYSNAME        COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NOT NULL,
                script                   varchar(4000)  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SERVERNAME,NAME,I)
            ) 

            exec sp_getthelogins @Radhe ='#Jagannatha'

            select *
            from #Jagannatha
```

that would show you something like this:
partial view with names changed to protect the innocent.

[image]

You could also script a single login, and avoid printing of the script - just look at the parameters.
have fun!

PS -> Sometimes you need to [look at permissions on master and msdb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242601/22336) when referring to server side permissions of an specific login.